# UIGestureRecognizer to Drag UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to build a `GestureRecognizer` to drag a `UIView` from right to left. If the user drag the View to the half of the screen, the View will be automatically dragged into the left corner to discard it, but if the user do not drag up to half the screen it will return to the corner right of the screen.
Little lost here, any tutorials or something?
Thanks

**EDIT :** Heres some code, its a `UIImageView`, inside a `UIScrollView`, i need to drag the entire scroll or just the image inside it :

```
_myScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.window.bounds.size.width, self.window.bounds.size.height)]; [_myScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.window.bounds.size.width , 1300)];

_tutorial = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.window.bounds.size.width, 1300)]; [_tutorial setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default"]];
_tutorial.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit; [_myScroll addSubview:_tutorial];

_tutorial.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    UIPanGestureRecognizer * recognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:_tutorial action:@selector(handlePan:)]; 
 [_tutorial addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];

    [self.window addSubview:_myScroll];
```

And the method i try to drag the `UIImageView`

```
- (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:_myScroll];
    recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x,
                                         recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:_myScroll];

}
```

Comment: I answered your question, but you should give more details on what you've tried, like "I can drag the view, but don't know how to make it go to the right position", ...

Comment: @rdurand yes, i can drag the view using a UIPanGestureRecognizer, but i don't know exactly how to detect the position, and then send the view to the desired position. And the second problem is, how to drag the view, only horizontally

Comment: Provide some code. Tell us what you tried, what *doesn't* work.

Comment: @rdurand Theres the code im trying to use,.

Comment: I added some code you can work on

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Have a look over [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6567/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-in-ios-5-pinches-pans-and-more). This is a `UIGestureRecognizer` tutorial which will give you the basics to handle pinch and pan gestures. Once you've learnt the basics, it's really easy to accomplish what you want. All you need is to check the position of the view once the pan is completed to send it to the correct position. Have a look at [this other tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content) on `UIScrollViews`, it may help you find your way through the second part.

Both tutorials come from [raywenderlich.com](http://www.raywenderlich.com), probably the most useful iOS tutorials site I know.

---

Here is some code on your `handlePan:` method you can work on :

```
- (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:_myScroll];

    recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x,
                                         recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

        // Check here for the position of the view when the user stops touching the screen

        // Set "CGFloat finalX" and "CGFloat finalY", depending on the last position of the touch

        // Use this to animate the position of your view to where you want
        [UIView animateWithDuration: aDuration
                              delay: 0 
                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut 
                         animations:^{
            CGPoint finalPoint = CGPointMake(finalX, finalY);
            recognizer.view.center = finalPoint; } 
                         completion:nil];
    }


    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:_myScroll];

}
```

I won't give you the perfect answer here, you'll have to work on the code to find a way to make it work as you want it to.

Here is one last tip. You can do some kind of "smooth" animation by using a slideFactor. It will help your animation being more "realistic". Work on this code, that you add right at the beginning of the "if":

```
CGPoint velocity = [recognizer velocityInView:self.view];
CGFloat magnitude = sqrtf((velocity.x * velocity.x) + (velocity.y * velocity.y));
CGFloat slideMult = magnitude / 200;

float slideFactor = 0.1 * slideMult; // Increase for more slide
```

Then in UIView `animateWithDuration:`, use `slideFactor` as the duration.