# How to move 2 objects add the same time in Xcode 4.6.3?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview

I have a view in Xcode 4.6.3's Interface Builder. And in this view I have **2** small UIImageViews. The first UIImageView is in the top half of the view and the second in the bottom half of the view. I want to move these 2 views at the same time (it's kind of multiplayer game for two players, when these two players move this UIImageViews **at the same time, but everyone in it's own direction**). The top UIImageView in top half of the view and the bottom UIImageView in bottom half of the view correspondingly. At the moment I have the code that allows me to move only one object (the object is "player" which is a bottom UIImageView):

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { 

       UITouch *drag = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
       player.center = CGPointMake(drag locationInView:self.view);

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: you have the deviation in points from one object. Why not use this same deviation for the second object in the same drag method?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I can't understand you :( Can you, please, explain in more detail?

Comment: from what I read it didn't seem a multiplayer kind of question. You want to be able to capture the touches of both objects and make them kinda do their own movements? Have you looked into using UIGestureRecognizers for each individual object that you place on your screen? If this is the case, look into this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13879666/uigesturerecognizer-to-drag-uiview. This q&a is pretty clear in how to achieve this. More so, this will probably allow u to have even more then 2 objects moving at the same time as i suspect you want.

Answer (score 0):

the `(NSSet *)touches` is sort of like an array of touches. If there are 2 touches detected on the screen, touches will have 2 objects. Enumerating through them like so:

```
NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches]; 
for (UITouch *touch in allTouches) {}
```

will give you an UITouch object so you can check to see which section of the screen it's in to see which player it is.

Btw `CGPointMake(drag locationInView:self.view)` should be `CGPointMake([drag locationInView:self.view])`