# How to use UIGestureRecognizer to scroll the webView

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

My app has one screen that consists of two views.

One transparent view on the top of one UIWebView.

All the events should be captured by transparent view when interacting using one finger.

And when interacting with two fingers, all events should bypass to the UIWebView. So users should be able to scroll the webview with two fingers.

My implementation that sets  `transparentView.userInteractionEnabled` to `NO` while the state becomes `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan`, and set it back to `YES` when the state becomes `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`
and it failed to work.

All source code is uploaded to this git repository
https://github.com/lihan/iosgesturetestproject

Part of code snippet

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action"];
    [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
    self.gr = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePaning:)];
    self.gr.maximumNumberOfTouches = 2;
    self.gr.minimumNumberOfTouches = 2;
    self.gr.delegate = self;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.gr];
}


- (void)handlePaning:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gr
{
    if (gr.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
        NSLog(@"Panning Began");
        self.transparentView.alpha = 0.8f;
        self.transparentView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

    }else if (gr.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        NSLog(@"Panning Ended");
        self.transparentView.alpha = 0.3f;
        self.transparentView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13879666/uigesturerecognizer-to-drag-uiview

Comment: @Abbie Thanks. I implemented that and found the webview does scroll now, but the areas you scrolled to are purely white, contents won't get rendered, any idea on this?

Comment: does the page takes some time to load??

Comment: NSString *string = @"Your web URL";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
[self.webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];

Comment: check whether u have called webview delegates

Comment: OR try this : webView.delegate = self;
NSURLRequest *urlRequest;
NSString *urlToOpen = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.stackoverflow.com"];
urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlToOpen]];
[self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];

Comment: Thanks again @abbie. All resolved.

Comment: Welcome again . Glad to help you